# Update value from one database to another database - fastest method

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables.
first datatable structure has nine columns but the important three are:

code | name | value

2D3 | name test | 0.12

the second table has the same three columns.

Now I want to update all rows of the first table with the values of table two where code AND name are the same as in table two.

So my current idea is to do a select of all rows of table 1 with the code and name columns, than check if a row with the same code and name exists in table 2, if yes get that value and do a UPDATE query in table 1 with value of table 2.

The problem is that the two tables are hugh and I am sure that I am not using the fastest method.
anyone an idea for the fastest method to do this? Thank you very much!

EDIT: the query:

```
$getall = "SELECT code, name, value FROM table2";
$query =  mysqli_query($conn, $getall );

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  $UpdateAll = "UPDATE table1 SET value = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$result["value"])."' WHERE name = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$result["name"])."' AND code = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$result["code"])."'";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateAll); }
```

Comment: You should add your (reduced version) query to the question

Comment: sorry! code added! thank you in advance ... the current code takes 120 seconds for ~10000 rows in each table, and is way too slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You speak of two databases but really mean two tables, don't you? In this case, you can do it with one update using a join, like this:

```
update table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t2.code = t1.code and t2.name = t1.name 
set t1.value = t2.value;
```

Comment: yes I speak of two tables ... sorry for the misunderstanding! thank you very much for the join hint! I will try this! So this would be the fastest way?

Comment: I just gave it a try and it seems to take even 10 seconds longer (130 seconds). hmm is there a faster solution?

Comment: Make sure that both tables have an index on `code` and `name`. If so, it should be way faster than sending hundreds of update requests. If it's still slow, you could convert the `update` query to a `select` and then use `explain` to see what's going on.

Comment: the 20000 rows of table2 are recreated every day (is there a way to add an index after the recreation process in php?) and table1 will be extended daily for >100000 rows and every row will be updated regularly, so an index on that table isn't a good idea, right?

Comment: You can use `alter table` to drop/add indexes before/after inserting new data but before doing this, you should do a benchmark to see if existing indexes really slow down inserts significantly.

Comment: so would you recommend a index for both tables? because I heard that you would not use an index on tables that are often changed/updated. ... What i could do is an index on the one that is recreated constantly. but would one index change anything?

Comment: You need an index on both tables to optimize performance when joining them. Updating data in tables with indexes requires that the indexes are updated too and thus data updates can be slower. You have to decide for every use case if indexes make sense or not, there's no universal answer. Therefore, benchmark the different scenarios and then decide which strategy to apply.